# sum number from dynamic input text JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, continuous-integration

hello guys i wanna ask something how can i sum number from dynamic field.

assume that i want to get total qty from my code and put into input type.
and how to calculate qty * harga and put into jumlah?
here is my code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var i = 0;
            $('#add').click(function () {
                var tanggal = document.getElementById('tanggal_n').value;
                var nama = document.getElementById('nama').value;
                var counter  = document.getElementById('Counter').value;
                var documentt = document.getElementById('id').value;
                i++;
                $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row' + i +
                    '" class="dynamic-added">'+
                    '<td><input type="text" name="addmore[' + i +'][nama_barang]"placeholder="Nama Barang" class="form-control jenis_list" required="" /></td>'+
                    '<td><input type="text" name="addmore[' + i +'][keterangan]"placeholder="Keterangan" class="form-control cost_list" required="" /></td>'+
                    '<td><input type="number" name="addmore[' + i +'][qty]"placeholder="QTY" id="qty"class="form-control qty_list" required="" /></td>'+
                    '<td><input type="text" name="addmore[' + i +'][harga]"placeholder="Harga" id="harga" class="form-control harga_list" required="" /></td>'+
                    '<td><input type="text" name="addmore[' + i +'][jumlah]"placeholder="Jumlah" id="jumlahDynamic" class="form-control jumlah_list" onchange = "sumData(this) required /></td>'+
                    '<td hidden><input type="text" value="'+tanggal+'" name="addmore[' + i +'][tanggal]" id="tanggal_get' + i + '" placeholder="tanggal"class="form-control jumlah_list" required="" /></td>'+
                    '<td hidden><input type="text" value="'+nama+'" name="addmore[' + i +'][nama_user]"  id="nama_get' + i + '" placeholder="nama"class="form-control jumlah_list" required="" /></td>'+
                    '<td hidden><input type="text" value="'+counter+'" name="addmore[' + i +'][noCounter]"  id="counter_get' + i + '" placeholder="Counter"class="form-control jumlah_list" required="" /></td>'+
                    '<td hidden><input type="text" value="'+documentt+'" name="addmore[' + i +'][noDocument]"  id="document_get' + i + '" placeholder="document"class="form-control jumlah_list" required="" /></td>'+
                    '<td><button type="button" name="remove" id="' +
                    i + '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');    
                // $('#tanggal_get' + i++).val(tanggal);
                // $('#nama_get'+ i++).val(nama);
            });
            $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function () {
                var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
                $('#row' + button_id + '').remove();
            });
        });
        

    </script>
```

thanks for helping guys

Comment: you are missing ```<div``` before class dynamic and ```>``` after id row

Comment: How is this question related to PHP? It seems like it's only about javascript/jquery/html